# slicing a dataframe via the startswith method

Tags: python, pandas

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['jfgh',23,'START',34,42,56], 'B':['cvb',7,'rtwf',65,87,23]})
```

Output:

```
       A     B
0   jfgh   cvb
1     23     7
2  START  rtwf
3     34    65
4     42    87
5     56    23
```

I would like to automatically extract the slice `df[3:6]`via the startswith method, ie I want to select the index relating to the value 34 and 23.

```
for index in range(len(df)):
    if df['A'].startswith('START'):
        df1 = df[index+1:len(df)]
        break
```

but it returns the AttributeError:
'Series' object has no attribute 'startswith'

I thought by selecting df['A'] it returns a series and thus enables the execution of startswith()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
if df['A'].startswith('START'):
```

to this:

```
if str(df.loc[index,'A']).startswith('START'):
```

**Full code:**

```
for index in range(len(df)):
    if str(df.loc[index,'A']).startswith('START'):
        df1 = df[index+1:len(df)]
        break
print(df1)
```

**Output**

```
    A   B
3  34  65
4  42  87
5  56  23
```

Comment: I have noticed that if I replace 'START' with some random lettering in the df but keep the same string 'START' in startswith() it returns the same answer